# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Build file 'C:\Users\mayev\dev\remplazo\Chronos\android\app\build.gradle' line: 81

Tags: javascript, android, build.gradle, react-native

I have been trying for hours to solve this, after configuring my application to login with facebook I got this error, I tried removing the facebook configuration but still the problem continues.

I am using react-native-fbsdk
react native version: 0.63.4
gradle version: 6.8.3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0T0Y.png)

Edit: My android development environment is well configured, because before adding the facebook configuration everything worked fine.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your android\app\build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

From the Screenshot, it clearly mentions that your Android Development Environment is not set.

You need to set up the **Android Development Environment** for creating android builds.

Here is how you can do it: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

If you have followed all the instructions and still facing this issue, then you can share the contents of your **./android/app/build.gradle** file

I will help you fix that too. Cheers!